# Styling polygons of postcode zones that contain a point (address)

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, style, within

I created a Map with Geocoded Addresses from the UK. The Basis for the map is a UK districts shapefile, this constitutes my main layer. After geocoding (via .csv) 3 Addresses I have a new layer with the three Address-Points.

[image]

The goal is now to create a Buffer around the Address Point that spans or fills out the entire area of the postcode to which that Address belongs. How can I implement this?

In the picture I included an example with a normal Buffer (just a circle with radius = x) the goal would be to fill the whole postal area with the Buffer.

Comment: Hi welcome to GIS SE. Please include a tag of what software you're using. Also there's no image attached.

Comment: there is no picture - wouldn't doing point in polygon and then coloring the polygons be easier than buffering?

Comment: Are you talking about Postcode Districts? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: Be aware about terminology: what you ask about is not a "buffer", but to apply a style to a polygon based on spatial relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention what software you are using but the workflow is the same for ArcGIS, ArcGIS Pro, or QGIS:

1. Create Voronoi polygons around your three points at an extent greater than the postcode polygon.  For QGIS see Voronoi Polygons in Processing tools under Vector Geometry.  For ArcGIS see ArcToolbox - Analysis Tools - Create Thiessen Polygons (advanced license only).
2. Clip the resulting Voronoi polygons with your postcode polygon. In QGIS try Vector Overlay - Clip, for ESRI try ArcToolbox - Analysis Tools - Extract - Clip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in filling the polygon would it not be more convenient to select the polygon based on the point location (Vector - Research Tools - Select by Location) and then saving these into a new polygon layer?

If you use this approach you would have to modify the polygon's attributes to reflect those of the point.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware about terminology: what you ask about is not a "buffer", but to apply a style to a polygon layer based on spatial relationship from another layer: highlight the polygon that contain points. Easiest to achieve this is to use [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) to add an additional symbol to the point layer: the polygon that the point is within.

To do so, on the point layer, add a new symbol layer of type `Geometry generator` and add this expression (replace `polygon` with the name of your postcode layer):

```
overlay_within('polygon',$geometry)[0]
```

*All countries that contain a red point are styled in blue filled style:*
[image]